# Ошибка во время компиляции проекта: SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near system_time

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект в MS Visual Studio 2015 из базы данных созданной в SQL Server2016.

Получаю ошибку: SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near system_time

В коде есть строки использующие фичу тeмпорал таблиц system_time , типа:

```
  SELECT 'actual' tbl, * INTO #my_table
    FROM
     my_table
    FOR system_time AS OF @dt
```

И Visual Studio не распознает system_time как валидный синтаксис.
Конечно это все работает SSMS 2016.

Пожалуйста помогите пофиксать вышеописанное

P.S.: set COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130 не помогло

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите

Comment: есть возможность мувнуть топик в мультиязычный форум?

Comment: Есть возможность тут удалить (а лучше - перевести с басурманского), а там создать.

Comment: как создается @dt? что в нем находится?

Comment: это тип datetime2 - определяется как значение даты из темпорал таблицы

Comment: Возможно выбрана неподходящая целевая платформа (_Target platform_ в свойствах проекта БД установите в _SQL Server 2016_).

Comment: все так и установлено изначально, не упомянул сразу